# Customize the 404 page in S3

Tags: amazon-s3

I'm almost a newbie in what respects to amazon buckets and instances, and what I have to do now is a custom error page for error 404. What is shown now is the default error page that shows an non-user-friendly XML telling that the file was not found.

Any ideas of a nice way to make this?

Answer (score 3):

I found the documentation to be extremely unclear. It says "provide this custom error document", which leaves me asking, "but how do I provide it?" It's in the S3 console, under the Properties tab, under "Static website hosting". But, you won't see it until you select the huge radio button beside "Use this bucket to host a website"

[image: Setting custom 404 page in S3 static website bucket]

Answer (score 2):

If you place CloudFront in front of S3 (your traffic costs will be lower) and it also allows you a far more fine-grained approach to how handling any errors (not just 404 errors)

Comment: I don't think this answers how to handle 404 pages.

Answer (score -1):

This is explained in the documentation.

> You can optionally provide a custom error document with a user-friendly error message and with additional help. You provide this custom error document as part of adding website configuration to your bucket. Amazon S3 returns your custom error document for only the HTTP 4XX class of error codes.
>
> <sup>— http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/CustomErrorDocSupport.html</sup>

Comment: Yes I was noticed about that, but that very brief explanation wasn't enough for me. Was looking for something like a step-by-step explanation, as I'm quite newbie in this area. BTW thanks for the answer.

Comment: Agree with you - it's not explained in that documentation.

What you should do is log into your S3 console > 'properties' tab > select the 'Static Website Hosting' option.

Here is where you would set your homepage (index.html default). You can also set your error page - just name it `error.html`, create a file with that name and put it in the root of your bucket.