# React App deployed on s3 bucket shows only the homepage. Hash router not working

Tags: reactjs, amazon-s3, react-router, react-router-dom, package.json

I deployed a react app on s3 bucket. Only the home page displays other pages does not display. I am getting 404 error on other pages. I have changed from `browserHistory` to `hashHistory` still the problem persist.

I am getting 404 error when I check the console.

index.js

```
<Provider store={store}>
  <HashRouter>
    <Theme>
      <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
        <App />
      </PersistGate>
    </Theme>
  </HashRouter>
</Provider>
```

App.js

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/manager/login" element={<Manager />} />
        <Route path="/receptionist/login" element={<Receptionist />} />
        <Route path="/" exact element={<Receptionist />} />
      </Routes>
    </div>
  )
}
```

I have also added home page to the package.json

```
"homepage": ".",
```

I ran npm build on my react app and got static files on the build folder

I moved the content of the build folder to s3 bucket I created.

I enabled static hosting on the bucket and also changed the bucket permission

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "PublicReadGetObject",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action": "s3:GetObject",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::marble-arch-prod/*"
    }
]
```

}

I unchecked the block access to allow traffic to the bucket.

Comment: Does this [section](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#s3-and-cloudfront) of the CRA deployments docs help? You might need to [edit] your post to include the deployment details as each server environment has different requirements/configurations.

Comment: I did what is on the blog but not working

Comment: Ok, like I said, editing your post to share what you've done or tried, including specific details for what is working or not working, is helpful and useful information.

Comment: I have modified my question

Answer (score 0):

You should configure your s3 website to redirect 404 to you index.html file. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59569493/7409146) explain how you can do.

The idea behind a Single Page Application, is the web server always serve the same page. If the page don't exist, thats the role of react-router to display it but the app loaded correctly.

Comment: If you believe this post already has an [answer](/q/19501718/8690857) then it's better to flag as a duplicate than to provide effectively a link-only answer. If you are unsure then leave a comment with a link to the other post/answer and explain the possible relationship.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have done that it did not work